# Rich text editor

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets

Hello all 
I want to add a text editor with my web application which should be light weighted and I am integrating with jquery.

I have used nicEdit but I am not comfortable with the document support of nicEdit.

Suggest me some good and simple text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE supports jQuery

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

Answer (score 1):

this is interesting and I'm trying to use it too: http://jqframework.com/jqrte